# Get properties files from multiple servlet contexts

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, classloader

I'm working on a web application that is spread over multiple contexts running inside one instance of tomcat.  The contexts are marked with `crossContext="true"` so that we can share some of the jsp between the different contexts. There is also a set of common classes that are part of the `common.loader` for tomcat.  We are to far away into the project to change this structure so please be sensitive to this structure when answering the question.

What I would like to do is get all the resources, say `com.something.messages`, that are present in all the different contexts.  Is this at all possible?  Should I record the class loader for each context created and use it to load the resources?  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already on Servlet 3.0, then you could use [`ServletContext#getClassLoader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getClassLoader%28%29) to obtain the servlet context's own class loader:

```
ServletContext otherContext = servletContext.getContext("/other");
ClassLoader otherClassLoader = otherContext.getClassLoader();
// ...
```

*(if this throws a security exception, edit the policy file accordingly)*

You could then pass this class loader into for example `ResourceBundle#getBundle()`:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale, otherClassLoader);
// ...
```

If that's not possible due to various reasons (e.g. not using Servlet 3.0 yet, or not willing to fiddle with policy files (very reasonable...), etc), then your best bet is to give each web application its own [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which loads the desired bundle and stores it as an attribute of the `ServletContext` during the `contextInitialized()` method. This way you can just get it as an attribute the usual way.